# Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv

I use `export-to-csv` to export a table data to csv format.
I am getting this error:

> unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.

```js
{toCSV && <ExportToCSV fileName={fileName} title={title} csvData={csvData} />}
export default function ExportToCSV (props) {
  const { title, fileName, csvData } = props
  const options = {
    filename: fileName,
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    quoteStrings: '"',
    decimalSeparator: '.',
    showLabels: true,
    title: title || 'ExcelReader File',
    showTitle: true,
    useTextFile: false,
    useBom: true,
    useKeysAsHeaders: true
  }
  const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options)
  csvExporter.generateCsv(csvData)
  return <div/>
}
```